# Tkinter - Bind lambda to rectangle on canvas

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

```
...
def bind(self):
    for x_num in range(10):
        for y_num in range(10):
            pixel = pix_array[x_num][y_num]
            self.canvas.tag_bind(pixel, "<Enter>", (lambda event, x=x_num, y=y_num: self.on_enter(x,y)))
...  
def on_enter(self, event, x, y):
    pass
```

Where `canvas` is a canvas fully initialized on a tkinter window `master`. Upon running this code, this error is thrown:

```
self.canvas.tag_bind(self.canvas.tag_bind(pixel, "<Enter>", (lambda event, x=x_num, y=y_num: self.on_enter(x,y)))
File "C:\(path removed)\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2447, in tag_bind
sequence, func, add)
File "C:\(path removed)\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1200, in _bind
self.tk.call(what + (sequence, cmd))
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".!canvas bind tagOrId ?sequence? ?command?"
```

Why is this error being thrown?

I can post more of the code if it is important, but it seems as the though the error is in the way I'm calling this function, or being caused by the way I understand it.

EDIT: Cause was `pix_array` not having assigned values at this point in the code.

Comment: Does the pix_array contain the ids or tags of the rectangles you created on the canvas? If not, that is what it is complaining about. The self.canvs.tag_bind command requires as its first argument, a tag or id of an item created previously on the canvas.

Comment: What is the value of `pixel` immediately before the line that throws the error? My guess is that it's `None`. Passing `None` as the first argument will give you this exact error.

Comment: My fault, bad testing. I printed out the contents of pix_array at a point in the code, which had the right IDs, but unfortunately I had overlooked some extraneous code which reset all values on it to None.